# How to setup a empty workspace before using the external setting in SVN

Tags: svn

you know we have the standard svn layout such as trunk, branches etc. we setting such as this layout for the modules, so before i set the external setting, so i will checkout all folders like trunk, branch, so i want to ask are there any way to setup a empty svn folder before we setting the external profiles? so i could fetch the specially files which i want in the external files.

thanks bunch.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to setup an empty folder by checking out a folder then create, add and commit the new directory.  Not sure what protocol and client you're using but from the command line with http:

```
> svn checkout http://server/repo/
A    repo/trunk
A    repo/branches
A    repo/tags
Checked out revision 1.
> cd repo/trunk
> mkdir project
> svn add project
A    project
> svn commit -m ""
Adding         trunk/project
Committed revision 2.
> echo done
done
```